# Do I need [weak self] or [unowned self] for a Singleton in the Closure?

Tags: swift, singleton, closures

```
class Test {

    private init() {}

    static let shared = Test()

    func test() {

    }

}

let closure: ()->Void = {
    Test.shared.test()
}

closure()
```

The code above is simple. But i want to know if I have to mark weak or unowned to the Singleton. And why?

Comment: No you don't because static/class variables are not bound to instances.  They are not retained and they don't cause an instance to be retained by a closure.

Comment: @ozgur what about `class` variables?

Answer (score 0):

No, because `self` is not used (explicitly or implicitly) in that closure.